# Azure subfolder redirect with ECMAScript format

Tags: javascript, azure, redirect, web-applications

All,
We have some vanity URLs that we use for HTTP redirection on an IIS server. We are looking to retire many servers due to techdebt. We have recently begun placing these vanity URLs into a Azure WebApp. We are using the following format for a 301 redirect

This works great for a Many->One HTTP redirect. What I am trying to accomplish is to listen on the subfolder level, but I don't know the proper syntax.

Can anyone assist with providing proper syntax for the  section?

Comment: You're post is missing the "301 redirect" format you're referring to.

Comment: <rule name="Ttesting.domainname.com" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://subdomain.domainname.com" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mysubdomain\.domainname\.com\\subfolder1" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>

Comment: After looking into it, it would seem like this is what I would need.


<rule name="Ttesting.domainname.com" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true"> <match url="(.*)" /> 
<action type="Redirect" url="subdomain.domainname.com" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"> 
     <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mysubdomain\.domainname\.com" /> 
     <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="subfolder1"/>
 </conditions> 
</rule>

Can anyone confirm?